Permission denied to publish to pubsub even though the service account has role Pub/Sub Publisher
I have a Cloud Run based micro-service that publishes messages to a GCP PubSub topic that works perfectly well when this service is called from an internal scheduled cron job but when this micro-service is called from an external third party api and then tries to publish a message to a topic I get this permission error: 'Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.'
This micro-service is running under a service account that includes the role Pub/Sub Publisher.  However, when I add the role Pub/Sub Admin to this service account it does work for these externally initiated calls!
I am trying to figure out which finer grained permission I need to add to this s.a. to make it work for external incoming messages and why is this?

Cloud Run micra-service works fine with internal calls but they will get dail with Permission_denied error for external calls due to insufficient IAM permissions. Pub/Sub Publisher will not check external requests. To fix this you need to create a custom IAM role for the service account with permissions. This doesnt require a Pub/Sub admin role and it is a safe practice.

Are you sure that the problem is on the message publishing? Are you sure that y our Cloud Run service is correctly invoked from the external 3rd party?

@guillaumeblaquiere positive - the cr service is invoked from our portal (at which point the service posts correctly to the PubSub) but can also be called 'externally' like through Postman when it gets this permission error.

@PranayKumarKyasala Not exactly sure what you mean - I have a custom role for the service account this CR runs under in which I have set Cloud SQL and other permissions it needs.  I only need this to Publish to PubSub which works when calling it through our web portal but not when called externally like a Postman call..

Try this troubleshooting steps which might be helpful :


Check external requests are authenticated properly.


Check Cloud Run service is set up to allow external invocations.


And the service account which you are using should have publish/get permissions.


Check network settings for any restrictions.



My point is not "if the cr service can be invoked externally (postman)", but if the service is correctly invoked (log trace, like hello when a request is received, whatever the source of the invocation) and then, the cr service write an error log. In addition screenshot or copy/paste of your cloud run service logs and configuration would be helpful
